# How to extract all values pointed to by an XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

I have the below xml

```
<test>
    <nodeA>
           <nodeB>key</nodeB>
           <nodeC>value1</nodeC>
    </nodeA>
    <nodeA>
           <nodeB>key</nodeB>
           <nodeC>value2</nodeC>
    </nodeA>
</test>
```

How to concatenate and get all the values in the xpath `/test/nodeA/nodeC` ?
My expected output in this scenario would be `value1value2`

I am not sure from what I have read that it is possible with xpath, but thanks for your help.

P.S: I am using [VTD-XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTD-XML) from Ximpleware to parse the same in Java. Any java based solution is also welcome. Currently my java solution gives only the first value, i.e. `value1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XPath will return a `NodeList` which you can iterate and concatenate:

```
StringBuilder concatenated = new StringBuilder():
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/test/nodeA/nodeC/text()";
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource("sample.xml");
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    concatenated.append(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: thank you, that pointed me in the right direction. Got it working now!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a groovy implementation (in 2 lines of code!) using [XmlSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html)

```
def xml = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parse(new File('sample.xml'))
print xml.nodeA*.nodeC.join("")
```

Outputs

```
value1value2
```

I don't use groovy in production code but for local mucking about it's great. I often have little groovy utilities in [gradle](https://gradle.org/) build files.

Comment: thank you. always love a groovy solution for its simplicity
but I cannot use this currently

Comment: yup... groovy has it's place... I'm just not sure it belongs in production code. Great for testing though

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single XPath expression to return the string with a concatenation of the selected values then you need XPath 2.0 (or later) respectively XQuery 1.0 (or later) where you can do `string-join(/test/nodeA/nodeC, '')`. XPath 1.0 does not have the expressive power to give you a string but of course, as already shown in another answer, you can iterate over the selected nodes and concatenate the selected values in a host language like Java.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with VTD-XML...

```
import com.ximpleware.*;


public class concat {
     public static void main(String[] s) throws VTDException{
         VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
         if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false))
             return;
         VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
         AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
         ap.selectXPath("/test/*/nodeC/text()");
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
         int i=0;
         while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
             sb.append(vn.toString(i));
         }
         System.out.println(sb.toString());
     }

}
```